# Unity Rotating Object Changes Position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello I have player using `Rigidbody2D`.

I've attached my camera to the player but when player rotates, camera is moving.
That's a problem for me, I want camera move only when player moves.

Here is a part of my code:

```
Rigidbody2D rb;

void Update() {

    rb.angularVelocity = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotateSpeed;

}
```

And Player's inspector:

[image]

So why does rotating object also changes position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've offsetted your rigidbody collider. If you have sprite and it is not centered, don't offset your collider. Offset your sprite.

[image]